# Unable to call a function using cUrl's set_opt

Tags: php, function, curl

I am trying to break down my code into functions. However, when I broke down the code to make `get_login_cookie()` function, the program stopped functioning as intended. I suspected its because the `curlResponseHeaderCallback` function isn't being called properly. Could someone help me fix it, so I can break my down into 2 functions.

---

**Original code (working just fine, and it print_r's the cookies just fine)**

```
<?php

function curlResponseHeaderCallback($ch, $headerLine) {
    global $cookies;
    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $headerLine, $cookie) == 1)
        $cookies[] = $cookie;
    return strlen($headerLine);
}


$url = "https://example.com/login";
$cookies = "";

$fields = [
    'username'      => "myuser",
    'password'      => "mypass",
];
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "curlResponseHeaderCallback"); // This is where the error is!
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_exec($ch);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cookies)


?>
```

---

**Break down the code into 2 functions (where code doesn't work properly) I get an empty array rather than the array of cookies. It most likely doesn't work because it I am not calling the `curlResponseHeaderCallback` function properly**

```
<?php

function curlResponseHeaderCallback($ch, $headerLine) {
    global $cookies;
    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $headerLine, $cookie) == 1)
        $cookies[] = $cookie;
    return strlen($headerLine);
}

function get_login_cookie() {
    $url = "https://example.com/login";
    $cookies = [];

    $fields = [
        'username'      => "myuser",
        'password'      => "mypass",
    ];
    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "curlResponseHeaderCallback"); // This is where the error is!
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    curl_exec($ch);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($cookies);
}

get_login_cookie();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `global $cookies;` in the second function.

The callback set data to the global $cookies, but you print the local $cookies.